# It is possible to populate @Transient lists from one Hibernate select?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, hibernate-criteria

I have a job list and I want to filter it. One Job can have a domain,department,position,studies,experience...

My job entity:

```
        @Entity
        @Table(name="JOB")
        public class Job extends BaseEntity{
        @Column(name = "title", nullable = false, length = 256)
        @NotNull @NotEmpty @Size(max=256)
        @Expose
        private String title;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="department_id")
        @Expose
        @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
        private Department department;


        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="position_id")
        @Expose
        @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
        private Position position;


        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="studies_id")
        @Expose
        @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
        private Studies studies;


        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="experience_id")
        @Expose
        @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
        private Experience experience;


        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="domain_id")
        @Expose
        @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
        private Domain domain;


        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="contract_type_id")
        @Expose
        @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
        private ContractType contractType;

        @Transient
        private List<Studies> studiesList = new ArrayList<Studies>();


        @Transient
        private List<Department> departmentsList = new ArrayList<Department>();


       @Transient
       private List<Position> positionList = new ArrayList<Position>();


       @Transient
       private List<ContractType> contractTypeList = new ArrayList<ContractType>();


       @Transient
       private List<Experience> experienceList = new ArrayList<Experience>();


       @Transient
       private List<Domain> domainList = new ArrayList<Domain>();
```

For each job attribute I do a findAll and I send to the page for the user to select one from them. It looks like this now:

```
        job.setStudiesList(studiesService.findAll());
        job.setDepartmentsList(departamentService.findAll());
        job.setPositionList(positionService.findAll());
        job.setExperienceList(experienceService.findAll());
        job.setContractTypeList(contractTypeService.findAll());
        job.setDomainList(domainService.findAll());
```

And it writes a lot of query when I load the page, I want to write all findAll in a single query and to put it in @Transient lists, is this possible? And if it is how?